# failed to execute this c++ code on android

Tags: c++, opengl-es, java-native-interface, android-ndk

i am trying to call native opengl methods from java. Everything compiles ok but i still get this horrible error in android log cat

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(536): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:init
                          at com.deo.Glut.Init(Native Method)
```

according to [oracle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError.html)

> UnsatisfiedLinkError is Thrown if the
>   Java Virtual Machine cannot find an
>   appropriate native-language definition
>   of a method declared native

i can't figure out why the emulator is failing to find my native methods.
//the native methods in glut.cpp (jni/glut.cpp)

```
#include<jni.h>//compiled using cgwin and ndk-build on windows xp
#include<gles/gl.h>
#include<math.h>

static void gluPerspective(GLfloat fovy, GLfloat aspect,
               GLfloat zNear, GLfloat zFar)//android ndk lacks glu tool kit (unbelievable)
{
    #define PI 3.1415926535897932f
    GLfloat xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax;

    ymax = zNear * (GLfloat)tan(fovy * PI / 360);
    ymin = -ymax;
    xmin = ymin * aspect;
    xmax = ymax * aspect;

    glFrustumx((GLfixed)(xmin * 65536), (GLfixed)(xmax * 65536),
               (GLfixed)(ymin * 65536), (GLfixed)(ymax * 65536),
               (GLfixed)(zNear * 65536), (GLfixed)(zFar * 65536));
    #undef PI
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_deo_Glut_display
  (JNIEnv *, jobject)
{
glClearColor(1,1,0,1);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_deo_Glut_reshape
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint width, jint height)
{
glViewport(0,0,width,height);
if(height==0)height=1;//prevent a divide by zero error in case it ever tries to occur
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
gluPerspective(50,width/height,1,1000);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_deo_Glut_init
  (JNIEnv *, jobject)
{}
```

I first declared then tried to call the above methods from java which is causing the error.

```
package com.deo;
public class Glut//java class that declares my native methods(src\com\deo\Glut.java)
{
    static
    {
       System.loadLibrary("glut");
    }
    public native void display();
    public native void reshape(int width, int height);
    public native void init();//this is somehow generating an error :(
}
```

then tried to call them from my custom renderer

```
public Glut myglut;
public   void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config)
{   myglut= new Glut();
    myglut.init();
}
```

Please help
[download link to project files](http://www.freefilehosting.net/nehe1)

Comment: Is `Java_com_deo_Glut_init` actually exported from your DLL? (Dependency Walker can help find out)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because your file is a cpp file, you will need `extern "C" { }` around your exported functions. Otherwise the compiler will mangle the function names and Java won't find the ones it's looking for.

Comment: Or use javah to generate a header file with the correct declarations and #include it

Comment: ahh!i had always noticed the extern c thing in cpp code but i used to safely ignore it until now :). Now i know why it should be there :)